# H1,H2,H3 etc are Smaller in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I have noticed that H1,H2,H3 etc font sizes are smaller in CKEditor than when They are displayed on a webpage. You can check at their demo page http://ckeditor.com/demo#full . What is the Solution of this Problem. I want to see the H1,H2,H3 ... font sizes as larger as they are displayed on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't adjust size of h1 h2 or h3 withnout changing your css style file. If you are able to do it, then do it.

But if you want to customize size of text in your particular article, you can use html tag, that just gets fixed size to the text. Here is an example.

`<font size="X" color="COLOR">This is the text of size "X"</font>`

Answer (score 0):

I notice nothing , everything is the same in CKEditor and in the preview as well.

Comment: I am not saying that the text is not same in Preview and CKEditor. I am saying that The Text Size is Lesser than it is displayed on a webpage. For Example. If You make a test.html file and put this code into it.
<html>

<body>
<h1>This is Sample Text</h1>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Stepo Yes, I have tried that and that works great. But the Problem is that When We Select any Text in CKEditor and Apply any Font Size to it, It does not wrap the text with <font size="x"> tag, rather it wraps it with <span style="font-size=x"> tag, which does not precisely make the font-size as larger in the CKEditor as it is displayed on the webpage.

Comment: Ah, gosh. Can you fiddle wysiswyg settings, or css sheet somehow?